# Unable to access facebook's Open Graph settings as the link 404's

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps, social-media

I have a facebook app that I use to authenticate people on a website, as well as post to stream.  I'm interested in using the open graph to set up my own objects, but when I edit my app's settings, and click on the 'open graph', I get a 404 'The page you requested was not found.'

I've tried creating a new App to see if I had messed up a setting, but the open graph link on that app also errors out.

I'm trying to follow the step by step on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/
but am unable to proceed to step 3 because the links don't work.

What am I missing here, and how am I able to edit the open graph settings on my app?

Thanks

Comment: Submit a bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: trying to do that now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that link should work. Please open a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/